# How to find index of object in array using multiple values with ES5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I am currently looking up objects in an array using one value, item number. However, if there happened to be multiple orders that both had the same item number on them, how could the particular object index be looked up using both values?

Object is structured in such a manner:

```
var object = {
    line: line,
    poNumber: purchaseOrder,
    item: item
};
```

Here is how I am looking the objects up now:

```
var posArrInd = posArr.map(function (x) { return x.item; }).indexOf(String(item));
var po = posArr[posArrInd];
var poLine = po.line;
```

Comment: So, to clarify - you have an array of objects. You want to find all indexes of those objects matching some condition and you can have more than one. Is that correct? Also, do you have to find *indexes* or can you work with just the objects?

Comment: There should only be one object that has a particular order number and item number, however, if just looking up objects by item number there could be multiple objects that are matched, so that is why I want to add the purchase order number to the criteria as well. Indexes or directly working with the objects are both fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6+

You can use .findIndex()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

```
var found = items.findIndex(function(itm) {
   return itm.number1 === number1 && itm.number2 === number2;
});
```

ES5:

Using .filter():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
var foundItems = items.filter(function(itm) {
   return itm.number1 === number1 && itm.number2 === number2;
});

if (foundItems && foundItems.length > 0) {
 var itemYouWant = foundItems[0];
}
```

Getting the index--you can have the index value returned as part of the filter method. Check out the docs for more examples.

Comment: `.findIndex` is not in ES5

Comment: AH you're right--well then filter will work--the same way but with the added and statement--you'll just have to expect a returned array with one item.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you could just use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if I am reading your question correctly. For example:

```
 var theItem = 'however your item numbers look'
 var matches = posArr.filter(function(x) { return x.item === theItem })
```

This will return an array of all things in `posArr` that have a particular item number specified in `theItem`

Comment: short: `posArr.filter(x=>x.item==theItem)`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski The question specifically notes es5, which is why I didn't use arrow functions.